# how to show time count down in angular app while loading of the app

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to show loader that will show the time in seconds while loading the app. Here is the code

**HTML**

```
<body>
  <div class="app-loader">
    <div class="loader-spinner">
      <div class="loading-text"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <angular-app></angular-app>
</body>
```

**Javascript**

```
(function loader() {
    var elAppLoader = document.querySelector("app-loader");
    var startTime = new Date();

    var counter = setInterval(() => {
       var seconds = Math.abs((new Date().getTime() - startTime.getTime()) / 1000);
       var elLoadingText = document.querySelector(".loading-text");
       elLoadingText.innerHTML = seconds.toFixed(2) + " s";
    }, 100);

    elAppLoader.addEventListener('app-loaded', function (event) {
      clearInterval(counter);
      elAppLoader.remove();
    });
})();
```

Now this works fine and shows the no of seconds on the screen after every 100ms but when the angular start loading the counter freezes until the angular gets loaded.

How can I solve this? Is this because JS is single threaded if so is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: do you have <app-loader> inside <app-root> or not? If so, move it to the body of index.html.

Comment: @JoshuaChan question updated!!

Comment: The counter freezes while Angular is loading and is removed after the app is loaded? If so, I believe web worker should be the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is beacause browser is busy parsing angular and all the loaded js.

The way to solve this is to use web worker.

Read more about it here: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webworkers.asp
It has a working timer example which suits your case

Comment: can you please provide code and I dont want to create extra flie for web worker